# Select where number of results is above x

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, limit

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  oh.date_added AS date_shipped, 
  o.date_added 
FROM 
  ".DB_PREFIX."order o , ".DB_PREFIX."order_history oh 
WHERE 
  o.order_id = oh.order_id 
  AND oh.order_status_id = 3
```

What I want to do is only show results if there are `X` or more rows with a particular date.

So if `X=5` there are three entries from the `2013-04-0`1, then they won't show,  but if there are nine entries (or anything `>= 5`) from `2013-04-02` then these results will be included in the query.

Once the requirements are met I would like the query to limit to that one group of rows from the matching date.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add nested `SELECT` to count these:

```
SELECT 
  oh.date_added AS date_shipped, 
  o.date_added 
FROM 
  ".DB_PREFIX."order o , ".DB_PREFIX."order_history oh 
WHERE 
  o.order_id = oh.order_id 
  AND oh.order_status_id = 3
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order o2 
              WHERE o2.date_added>"2013-04-01") > 5
```

Or join a table on itself, along the lines

```
SELECT 
  o.date,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM 
  order o
  JOIN order o2 ON o2.date = o.date AND o2.id != o.id
WHERE 
  your conditions
GROUP BY o2.id
HAVING cnt > 5
```